# Call javascript variable in html link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a javascript word from a list and put it in a html link.
Like this but it isn't working.:

```
<a href="http://wikipedia.org/wiki/<"class="type>">
    Read more
</a>
```

I want one of these words in the link (I set it to random)

```
var game = { 
    type : ['One', 'Two', 'Three', ], 

function idea(el) {
    var i = el.length, 
        j, 
        temp;

    if ( i == 0 ) 
        return;

    while ( --i ) {
        j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) ); 
        temp = el[i];
        el[i] =el[j];
        el[j] = temp;
    }

    return el[0];
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are actually trying to accomplish. Where do you want the word? How are you calling it? How are you trying to add the word to the link?

Comment: <"class="type> takes a random word from var game = {type...}. I want a word in the end of a link

Comment: Well JavaScript does not get called like that so there would be the first issue. Create a method that reads the links and updates the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
var game = {
  type: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
}

function getRandom(t, el) {
  el.href += game[t][Math.floor(Math.random() * game[t].length)];
}
```

```html
<a href="http://wikipedia.org/wiki/" onclick="getRandom('type', this)">
    Read more
</a>
```